# object with array to .xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Main.java

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

// output pretty printed
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

Appointment.java

```
public class Appointment{
    private Integer day;
    private Integer numbOfVisitors;
    private String comment;
    //setters with @XmlAttribute and getters
}
```

Customer.java

```
    public class Customer{ 
private String name; 
private String surname; 
private int expirience;
private Appointment[] appointments; 
//setters with @XmlAttribute and getters 
}
```

How i can Marshall 2 objects in .xml like this? Becouse this code Marshall only customer name and surname

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer Name="Anton" Surname="Vasiliev" Expirience="3252" >
    <Appointment Day="1" NumbOfVisitors="4" Comment="gdshfgfh" />
    <Appointment Day="2" NumbOfVisitors="2" Comment="dgsh242fd" />
    <Appointment Day="3" NumbOfVisitors="6" Comment="bdgsrjdfgsryw" />
    <Appointment Day="4" NumbOfVisitors="3" Comment="1dgfhhhsqqe" />
</Customer>
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB does not work with arrays by nature because Java does not have dynamic arrays. Instead declare your Appointment as ArrayList.

it must be initialized either with class or in getter

```
private List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList();
```

or in getter

```
public List<Appointment> getAppointments() {
    if (appointments == null) {
        appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    }
    return this.appointments;
}
```